# scanf of backspace (0x08) and EOT(0x04)

Tags: c, backspace

Can anybody say me which input I have to give on terminal to get 0x0804857d saved in the memory. The used function is scanf("%s", array) ic C language.

The problem is that 08 equals to Backspace which is impossible to input or 04 = EOT. I mustn't change the code...

Maybe its impossible, I don't know

Please help me...

Comment: feed stdin from outside. don't type.

Comment: Can you redirect terminal to a file? That is, run `program < file` instead of `program`? If yes, I think it's the simplest way.

Comment: Cannot _only_ save 0x0804857 in memory.  Using `scanf("%s", array)` will always (given that some input occurred) append a `'\0'`.  Suggest posting the `scanf("%s", array)` use and nearby code to better understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not use the `scanf` function to read binary data. Use `read`/`fread` instead.